# Sitecore BucketItem folders versioning issue

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

I am currently having issue with BucketItem folders. My bucket folder structure is Year/Month/Day (2014/10/16).

[image]

I can see the version of my bucket item folders and bucket item in master database once I create bucket item.

[image]

Then I published bucket item (in to web databse), I can’t see the version of the bucket folders. But bucket item has the version.

[image]

Sitecore version :- Sitecore.NET 7.2 (rev. 140526)   (Clean installation).

I have tested some other instances as well, those all gave me same behaviour. 
Can someone help me to figure out what’s happening here? Much appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug. Haven't looked deep into it, but I solved this one locally by:-

Go to this item.

```
master:/sitecore/templates/System/Item Buckets/Bucket
```

(Note: You're going to the template item itself, not it's Standard Values item).

Enable Standard Fields, and go to the Publishing section.
Go to Publishing Targets and explicitly tick all of your publishing targets.

Publish the template item.

Republish your content items.

I personally don't like this, because explicitly setting your publishing targets will be bad if you add more publishing targets later.... but it seemed to fix the problem for me for the moment.

Comment: Thanks Sean for quick reply, I have tested(in two instances) the your suggestion but didn't work for me.